# Carbon or CF to list contents of a directory (OS X and C++)

Tags: c++, macos-carbon, core-foundation

How do I use Carbon or CoreFoundation (preferably the latter) to list the contents of a directory?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CoreFoundation has any way to do it.  With Carbon, one could use repeated calls to FSGetCatalogInfoBulk.  But, just curious, why not use BSD or Cocoa methods?

Comment: I can't use Cocoa as this project must be in C++, and no, Objective-C++ is not an option here.  I can't really use BSD functions cleanly as I'm looking for the same list of files I'd get in Finder.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "same list of files I'd get in Finder".  Same order?  Same files hidden?  Using Carbon will not guarantee either of those.

Comment: The BSD functions will also show those special Unix files like ".", ".DS_Store", etc.  While I probably can write more code to filter those out, I just want to know if there's a cleaner and more OS X-like way to do it with Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CFURLEnumerator, but it is available for 10.6 only.